# Schema error in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i am new to mysql database programming and i have tried to create a procedure but it failes and give me error like

> Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4:

The code am using is

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5);



CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
set p1 = 'ID';
select p1 from CUSTOMERS;
END;
```

..What am doing here for causing a syntax error ??.Can anyone point out my mistake...

Thanx

Comment: Unrelated but, you most probably do **not** want `char` but `varchar`. `char` columns are always padded with spaces to the defined length. So if you store `'1'` in `char(10)` column, the database will store `'1'` padded with 9 space characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`new_procedure` (p1 INT)
BEGIN
set p1 = 'ID';
select p1 from CUSTOMERS;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Let me add a little explanation: When creating a procedure, you must replace the default sentence terminator `;` with a custom one (in this case `$$`) so you can write the instructions inside your procedure using the default terminator. After your procedure is complete, you must end the procedure with the custom terminator, and then restore the default one, so you can keep on writing queries and instructions in the usual way

Comment: @Barranka it didnt helped me at all..can you please post a working example on sql fiddle

Comment: @4EACH no this didnt worked ..it raises the same error..It would be really helpgul if you post a working sample on sql fiddle

Comment: Use phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, dont use web tools for issues like this the error that i got in sqlfiddle that i cant run STORAGE PROCEDURE :) take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e61b6/1

Answer (score 0):

After reading carefully your question, I think I've figured out.

[4EACH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311909/schema-error-in-mysql/26312000#26312000) is right about the delimiter thing (and I commented accordingly). But there's something misssing yet:

First, you are trying to assign `p1` a text value, and it's already defined in your procedure as an `INT` parameter! If you want it to be a text value, you need to declare it at the beginning of your procedure. Second, you're trying to build a dynamic SQL expression inside the procedure... and that's not the way to do it! If you want to do that, you'll need to use prepared statements.

A possible solution:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE new_procedure ()
BEGIN
    declare p1 varchar;
    declare sql text;

    set p1 = 'ID';
    set sql = concat('select `', p1, '` from CUSTOMERS');
    prepare stmt from sql;
    execute stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Ok, I'll leave the above code as it is, but I must say: **it is wrong**. [Quoting from the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html):

> A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have session scope; see [Section 9.4, “User-Defined Variables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

So, the punch line is: If you want to define this sort of thing, then you must use User variables. Notice that they are not declared, but are initialized at the first assignment:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE new_procedure ()
BEGIN
    set @p1 = 'ID';
    set @sql = concat('select `', p1, '` from CUSTOMERS');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And yes, [here is your SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d96c/1)

---

Answering your comment:

> But how can I pass the column name in a variable?

Here's a way:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE new_procedure (col varchar(255))
BEGIN
    set @p1 = col;
    set @sql = concat('select `', @p1, '` from CUSTOMERS');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

[And here's the example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35357/1)

---

Using stored procedures to do this kind of things is... cumbersome, because you need to prepare a statement inside them, but to do that, you must use user-variables that tanscend the scope of the procedure (you can't use local variables to create a prepared statement). If you want to do this without a procedure, you can do something like this:

```
set @cols = 'id, name'; -- If you want, enclose them in back-ticks: '`id`, `name`'
set @sql = concat_ws(' ', 'select', @cols, 'from your_table');
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
-- When you are done, deallocate the prepared statement
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: ..no its not the problem ..i get the same error ..can u run this code on sql fiddle ..?? when i run it i got error

Comment: Use phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, the error that i got in sqlfiddle that i cant run PROCEDURE :)

Comment: @frgdgdfgdfgdgdgd not only the delimiter... the *other* problem is that you are trying to build a dynamic SQL expression, and you must do it with prepared statements

Comment: @Barranka hey thanks ..but how can i pass the column name in a variable ??